# iOS convert a region defined in polar coordinates to an NxN matrix

Tags: ios, image, math, matrix

Ok, so the situation is that I want to create an NxN matrix representing the pixels of a bitmap image. 
Then, I want to change the value of all those pixels which fall in a certain region to a constant value.

The region is defined using polar coordinates.

For example, 
            let the matrix represent a 2048x2048 pixel bitmap, and the region be defined by 25<=r<200, 0<=theta<π/4, and I want to set the value of all those points that fall in that region to some constant, k (defined elsewhere).

What's the best way to go about this?  
 
Should I look at any of Apple's libraries, such as vImage, or parts of the Accelerate framework, etc, 
or is this something so specific that I'll have to tackle it by hand, going over each pixel in my NxN matrix to see if it lies in the region of interest?

It seems like there has to be a more efficient way to do it than just hard coding a couple of for loops.  Especially if the region had some arbitrary definition, say a squiggly loop drawn by a user.

Advice?

Comment: I should mention that the purpose is to be able to do math on the matrix and later convert it to an image, specifically to make a heat map.

Answer (score 1):

Accelerate Framework provides a lot of functions for working with images.

In your case I'd recommend [vImage Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/performance/Conceptual/vImage/Introduction/Introduction.html), which has vImageTableLookUp_* functions for image transformation using [lookup tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table).

For example, if *red* values from 25 to 200 should be constant number, you create an array

```
int red[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    if (i >= 25 && i < 200) {
        red[i] = MY_CONSTANT_VALUE;
    } else {
        red[i] = i;
    }
}
```

and pass that array to the function above.